# How to find the maximum number in python repeatedly from a group of numbers

Tags: python, loops

I have a numpy array like below:

```
[12,544,73,56,30,84,34,29,78,22,73,23,98,83,35,62,52,94,44,67]
```

In this data there are 20 numbers and they are divided in 4 groups with 5 numbers in each group. so for ex.

```
12,544,73,56,30
84,34,29,78,22 etc.
```

I want to find out the maximum number from each group and store them in a list.
Like:

```
sol=[544,84,98,94]
```

I am very new to python please help.

Comment: split into chunks and compute max for each one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by splitting 1st then find out the max.

```
x = np.array([12,544,73,56,30,84,34,29,78,22,73,23,98,83,35,62,52,94,44,67])
n = 4
res = np.array(np.array_split(x, n)).max(axis=1)
```

---

**res:**

```
array([544,  84,  98,  94])
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
import pandas as pd
field = [12,544,73,56,30,84,34,29,78,22,73,23,98,83,35,62,52,94,44,67]
field = pd.DataFrame(field)
field.rolling(window = 5, win_type = None).max().iloc[4::5]
```

gives:

```
4   544.0
9   84.0
14  98.0
19  94.0
```

Every 5th step

*Update*
and a much faster one:

```
field = np.array([12,544,73,56,30,84,34,29,78,22,73,23,98,83,35,62,52,94,44,67])
field.reshape(-1, 5).max(axis=1)
```

Comment: Remove numpy from import as solution doesn't use it.